# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound, but parameters are provided

Tags: php, pdo

I'm building a database object that joins the `PDO` object with the `PDOStatement` object in order for chaining to be available. Basically I just put the methods I most frequently use, but `bindParam` is giving me a hard time.

```
private $stmt = null;

...

public function prepare($statement,array $driver_options = array()) {
    if($this->stmt) throw new \Exception('PDO Statement already prepared, no override!');
    $this->stmt = parent::prepare($statement, $driver_options);
    return $this;
}

public function bindParam($place, &$val, $dataType){
    if(!$this->stmt) throw new \Exception('PDO Statement is empty');
    $this->stmt->bindParam($place, $val, $dataType);
    return $this;
}

public function execute(array $params = array()){
    if(!$this->stmt) throw new \Exception('PDO Statement is empty');
    $this->stmt->execute($params);
    return $this;
}

public function fetchAll($pdoFetchType){
    if(!$this->stmt) throw new \Exception('PDO Statement is empty');
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll($pdoFetchType);
}

...

public function getStmt(){
    return $this->stmt;
}

public function clearStmt(){
    $this->stmt = null;
}
```

I get the error, from the title, in this code:

```
$i = 0;
$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users LIMIT ?,1')->bindParam(1, $i, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
while($row = $db->execute()->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "<pre>".print_r($row, true)."</pre>";
    $i++;
}
```

Basically what I found out about this error is that it occurs when provided variables in `bindParam` are `null`, but `$i` is clearly not null. Can you help me out?

**EDIT**: Also running

```
var_dump($this->stmt->bindParam($place, $val, $dataType));
```

in the `bindParam` method returns `TRUE`. From the manual:

> Return Values
>
> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

It's succeeding but not binding the parameter ??? I feel my brain is going to explode soon.

Comment: What happens if you put `var_dump($val)` inside the your defined `bindParam()`? And if you put `var_dump($this->stmt)`?

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia `int(0)` `object(PDOStatement)#6 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(29) "SELECT * FROM users LIMIT ?,1" }` I really hate it when `php` does that to me..

Comment: I'm running out of ideas, try `bindValue()` instead of `bindParam()` inside of your function `public function bindParam` to see if something changes. From the doc, *Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.* but I'm not sure if it'd change anything.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia even the error message stayed the same, at least that could've changed.. `Q_Q`

Comment: The debugger is your friend.

Comment: Your main problem is that you made your class stateful. Do not return $this, but PDO statement. The idea is interesting though, I'd think of implementation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess using a reference `&$val` instead of a value `$val` is what causes the issue.

Please try this code instead:

```
public function bindParam($place, $val, $dataType)
{
    if(!$this->stmt) throw new \Exception('PDO Statement is empty');
    $this->stmt->bindParam($place, $val, $dataType);
    return $this;
}
```

**EDIT**

My above answer is wrong.

Try modifying the `execute` method:

```
public function execute(array $params = array()){
    if(!$this->stmt) throw new \Exception('PDO Statement is empty');
    $this->stmt->execute();
    return $this;
}
```

Passing an empty array as parametre to the `execute` method removes all previous bindings. This is why `bindParam` returned true (successfully bound), yet the "no params were bound" error appeared as soon as you called `execute`.

Comment: It used to be without a reference, still got the same error. I added the reference because without it, wrapping the parent `bindParam` like this just makes no sense

Comment: References are dangerous and it's easy to break things. Please try running your loop and calling `bindParam` in each iteration with the updated `$i` value instead of relying on the reference. I'm sure it will work as expected.

Comment: It doesn't. And references aren't dangerous when they're used right. If the original `PDO` function `bindParam` uses a reference, then there must be a good reason for that, as there is. I tried what you suggested anyway and, sadly, the error is the same.

Comment: I hereby retire my claims regarding your supposed reference misuse - see my edited answer.

Comment: One of these things that makes you wanna go "How in the H did I not see this". Thank you very much sir!

Comment: Glad to have been able to help.

Answer (score 5):

Got the same error, but different cause

My request had comments, one of which included a damn **question mark**.

For PDO, a "`?`" is, of course, a parameter to bind.

*My request had no issue anywhere else, and I had no idea where PDO would invent a "parameter" while I wasn't using any, since I always use named placeholders, like* `:value`

Spent more than one hour on this :(

 May this answer help some people having this foolishly trivial issue.

Comment: Oh, nice catch - thank you! Had the same issue with Yii 1.1 on upgrading the server to PHP7.2 and MySQL 5.7.