# PHP Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I use PDO to execute sql

```
"INSERT INTO zhushou_cost_uid
(uid,imei,wmac,imsi,channel,supplier,uuid,brand,device_model,os,os_version,app_version,promotion_method,log_source,takeup_date)
 VALUES
('863207010118070','863207010118070','02037ff459cb','460025323359694','sc-hjcx_ins_cgq','','�ܟ*c�1�]�y�.���#���h���!�o ��z�!Y�~��t8�KOd�xd]���sm����n%$����H����[?�p���M����','KINGSUN','KINGSUN S6','Android','4.1.2','3.2','','1','2015-11-29 03:21:21')",
```

PHP code:

```
$db = $this->getWritableDB();
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$exec = $stmt->execute();
```

the data of uuid is dirty data, and in our log it is

> "uuid":"�ܟ*c�1�]�y�.���#��\u0015�h\u001a���!\u001c�\u0013o �\u0013�z�\u0000!Y�~��t8�KOd�xd]�\u0001��sm\u0016����\u0001n\u0013%$����H����[\u0003?�p���M��\u001a��"

I got the result

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound.

When I try to copy the sql onto the terminator, exiting the mysql login status. I think there is something wrong in uuid. But I can not figure out it. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: Copy the SQL to the terminator which leads to exit mysql login status, I am so confused.

Comment: Please post your php code. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436745/sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number-no-parameters-were-bound-but-paramet

Comment: Our php code likes this(the SQL is in my question):  $db = $this->getWritableDB();
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);                                                                                $exec = $stmt->execute();

Comment: Update your question with that code, don't leave it in a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
> ```

Since you're *preparing* your statement, if there's anything in it that can be interpreted as a question mark or colon, it will be taken as a placeholder and you're expected to then pass values for it in the `execute` step. Since this is not actually what you're intending, **don't `prepare` the statement if you don't intend to have placeholders in it.** Instead:

```
$db->exec($sql);
```

Having said that, it's suspicious that you're passing a fully formed SQL query in `$sql`; perhaps you *should* be rewriting this whole thing so you do have actual placeholders in your query and are passing the actual values separately to `execute`.

Comment: I tried what you said, the SQL executed successfully, thanks very much.